# Soap call with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, cors

I am asked to make an soap call to a public webservice (www.webserviceX.net) with pure JavaScript (using JavaScript libraries are fine) on a web page.

As far as I know I need to use server side code due to the same origin policy ?

concerning webseviceX.net does it support CORS ?

How do I check it ?

Comment: Check the headers in the response.  Look for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you need to make some changes client side to allow a CORS, the server also needs to support it as the browser will first make an `OPTIONS` call and will expect certain headers to be returned before it will make the actual SOAP call afterwards.

There is [more detail on CORS here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201211/Blog/Using-CORS-With-ASP-NET-Web-API/), although it relates to ASP.NET Web API, the server side parts are equally true for a SOAP service.

Comment: i came accross the 'OPTIONS' request but i didnt see any 'Acces-control-allow-origin' header ,i quess it means cors si not supported.

Comment: The service provider would need to add support - or you can use JSONP potentially as a fallback.

Comment: I dont own the webservice and it only uses soap :(